# Модули в Python

Tags: python, list

Можете помочь - обьяснить по теме модули в python?

1. Создайте свой модуль и подключите его в основном файле.
2. Напишите в модули 3 функции, каждая из которых принимает список. Первая функция – получение максимального значения, вторая – получение минимального значения, третья – получение суммы всех элементов.
3. Проверьте работу этих функций в основном файле.

я создал свой модуль - mymodule и написал код, который требуется в задаче

**mymodule.py**

```
def max(list):
    print(max(list))

def min(list):
    print(min(list))

def sub(list):
    print(sum(list))
```

в основном файле импортировал свой модуле  и написал

**main.py**

```
from mymodule import *

list = input('Введите список: ')
```

но в ответе пусто, что же я не дописал???
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Называть переменные именами встроенных типов - худшая идея. А недописаны, к слову, вызовы методов из соседнего модуля. Ввод с клавиатуры вы приняли, а что дальше-то? В программе ничего не написано об этом - просто завершаем работу. `input` - возвращает не просто список, а список символов, строку, по-другому. Чтобы получился список чисел, надо будет еще что-то сделать.

Answer (score 2):

1. Не используйте зарезервированное слово `list` как имя переменной
2. Не используйте имена стандартных функций `sum`, `max`, `min`.
3. Вы не вызвали ваши функции.
4. Предлагаю сделать вам так:

**mymodule.py**

```
def maximum(arr):
    return max(arr)

def minimum(arr):
    return min(arr)

def summa(arr):
    return sum(arr)
```

**main.py**

```
from mymodule import *

arr = list(map(int, input('Введите список: ').split()))
print(maximum(arr))
print(minimum(arr))
print(summa(arr))
```